# Utilize ubuntu workspace for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, workspace

I find the workspace division of Ubuntu very helpful. I can place several maximized windows on different workspaces and use keyboard to quickly switch between them.

In eclipse, there's sometime I want to have quick access to two different documents. Eclipse have a feature that allow me to dock two document in parallel, but it has a limit: that the screen size.

Now I want to have two eclipse editor windows on two different "Ubuntu workspace" accessing the same "Eclipse project" (or same "Eclipse workspace"), so that I can switch between them with Ubuntu shortcut key.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the menu: "Window -> New Window". Done!